# Traversing tree nodes in C#

Tags: winforms, data-structures, c#-3.0

For some reason, we have transformed our application XML configuration file to the format in which it's represented as tree nodes in a tree control. (Depth of tree node is not limited.)

XML Element names are transformed to tree nodes and at every node their would be value corresponding to that XML element. (i.e. In our Winform application, we show the XML document in Tree control. Every element is one Tree node and it's corresponding value is displayed in the text box. BUT i cannot use control's properties.)

**Now I need to search a node (XML element) string from any depth to up in the hierarchy up to grandparent.**

How can I achieve it in C# 3.0?

Comment: What does the data structure look like?

Comment: I'm confused when you say that you "transformed" your "application XML configuration file to the format in which it's represented as tree nodes."   XML files are *already* a hierarchical tree-structure of nodes.  What did this transformation accomplish?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I mean in my Winform application, we show the XML document in Tree control. Every element is one Tree node and it's corresponding value is displayed in the text box. I've updated question as well.